# What can one say about the eigen spectrum of the Hadamard or pointwise product of two matrices A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds, hadamard-product

Can we give bounds or infer any type of information about the spectrum of the point-wise product of two matrices $A$ and $B$ given knowledge about the spectrum of $A$ and $B$ ?

Are there non trivial conditions on $A$ and $B$ that would make reasoning about these easier ?

The inequality on the product of eigenvalues at this [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#Schur_product_theorem) on Wikipedia reproduced here:

$$\det({A} \circ {B}) \ge \det({A}) \det({B}).$$

is already a nice result.

$$ \operatorname{rank}(A \circ B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) \operatorname{rank}(B)  $$

as well. Are there other known inequalities involving eigenvalues ?  Can one infer anything about individual eigenvalues ? Maybe the dominant ones ?

**Edit :** There are nice inequalities on the spectral radius in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2706288/1049002 and in the comment below. This question might be a bit of a duplicate of that one but maybe some new proofs were found specifically for eigenvalues and eigenvectors since.

**Edit 2 :** This answer https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/29071 claims that not much can be known in general. [**Edit 3 :** but it does provide a link to a paper that seems to show some inequalities.]